# Blazor WebApp .Net8 Application State

Tags: web-applications, blazor, .net-8.0, cascadingparameter, cascadingvalue

Following Carl Franklin's application state management in blazor doesn't seem to work in .Net 8.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4WPuGwxZKIA

The local storage instance and the renderfragment appear to be null. in addition getting The render handle is not yet assigned when calling statehaschanged() in the cascading app state throws the following exception "The render handle is not yet assigned."

Here's the github repo the project

https://github.com/vconfrence/BlazorApp1.git

CascadingAppState component which is meant to be a root level cascading value available through cascading parameter within any compoenent doesn't seem to work. LocalStorage and other variables don't seem to be initializing.

Also followed guidelines posted by Microsoft which didn't work

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/cascading-values-and-parameters?preserve-view=true&view=aspnetcore-8.0#root-level-cascading-values

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-7.0&pivots=server#handle-prerendering

Comment: The web app with auth demonstrates how to persist state in .net 8. The template uses `PersistentAuthenticationStateProvider` that injects the `PersistentComponentState`.

Comment: Net8 moved the goalposts for component design.  RenderMode introduced operational contexts that did not exist pre Net8.  Some solutions break in certain Net8 deployment contexts.  I had a quick look at your solution.  It looks like you are trying to operate in some type of mixed mode which will certainly break some pre Net8 solutions.  App `HeadOutlet` set to *InteractiveAuto* and `Routes` set to *InteractiveServer*.

Comment: Appreciate comments/suggestions. Provided project is created entirely in .Net 8 web app project however doesn't seem to handle app state as expected.